# Boost thread: Term does not evaluate to function taking 0 arguments

Tags: c++, boost

**Version info**: I'm using boost 1.64 and Visual Studio 2015

I'm having a hard time understanding this boost compilation error.

My sample code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost\thread.hpp>

using namespace std;

void testfunc(vector<int> &first, vector<string> &second)
{
    first.push_back(42);
    cout << "I live." << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> first;
    vector<string> second;
    unique_ptr<boost::thread> thr = make_unique<boost::thread>(new boost::thread(testfunc, boost::ref(first), boost::ref(second)));

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation fails with the error: `boost\thread\detail\thread.hpp(116): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments`

Why is it trying to compile it as a function that takes 0 parameters? Shouldn't the two extra arguments passed to the `boost::thread`constructor tell boost the number of parameters `testfunc` takes?

## EDIT:

The problem doesn't seem to be the `boost::thread` constructor, but the `unique_ptr` that wraps the pointer. Without it, the code compiles.
As for why that happens, I'm still without a clue.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition oops looked at a wring ctor.

Comment: Do you even want a `unique_ptr<boost::thread>`? Could you use `boost::thread` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Boost, or vectors, or strings, or threads.

You're using `make_unique<T>` wrong here:

```
make_unique<boost::thread>(new boost::thread(testfunc, boost::ref(first), boost::ref(second)));
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It takes arguments to construct the `T`, but you're passing it a raw pointer to an already-constructed object. `boost::thread` doesn't know what to do with a `boost::thread*`.

You should instead write simply:

```
make_unique<boost::thread>(testfunc, boost::ref(first), boost::ref(second));
```

Comment: That is the problem indeed.... I'm using make_unique with the parameters I'd pass to the unique_ptr constructor. Thanks for the catch!